# List intersection with O(n·m)

Tags: algorithm, list, math

Suppose we have two lists of lengths n and m respectively:

```
val l1 = Seq(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0)
val l2 = Seq(2,4,6,8,10,12)
```

Is there a way to calculate their intersection wiht less than O(n·m)?

That is

```
val result = Seq(2,4,6,8)
```

**EDIT**: we can assume our lists are sorted.

Comment: Can we assume that the lists are sorted?

Comment: Let's try without that asumption first.

Comment: It's actually easier if we try it *with* that assumption first, because the way to do it with unsorted lists starts with sorting them.

Comment: Ok, let's try then assuming we have sorted list. Thanks!

Comment: I mean elements in common in both lists. As if the lists were considered sets.

Comment: @Beta  What do you mean?  By sorting you're already at O(n log n) when you can find intersection at O(n).

Comment: @wim: [facepalm] I always forget about hash tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For sorted lists the following Algorithm should work:

You can have 2 pointers say (i and j) one at l1 another at l2.

Now you can iterate on l1 and l2 such that

```
 while (i< l1.size && j < l2.size ) {
    if l1[i] < l2[j] 
       i++ 
    else if (l1[i] == l2[j] )
       i++; j++; output = output U {l1[i]}
    else
       j++  
 }
```

This should be in O(max(m,n))

Comment: This is the better solution.  It relies only on linearly scanning both lists with no extra memory needed.  In fact, this is similar to the way C++ [`std::set_intersection`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_intersection) does it.

Answer (score 2):

1. Put one of the items into a hash set.  O(min(n,m))

   ```
   var set2 = new HashSet<int>(){2,4,6,8,10,12};
   ```
2. Take the other set and check if it exists in hash set. Each access is O(1) since we need the other set and we created the hash set with the shorter set that means the time is O(max(m,n)) if it return true in the other set 
   add it to your results.
3. Result is O(n+m) in time and O(min(n,m)) in memory.

Comment: I'm interested in the algorithm more than a way of program it. But thanks!

Comment: You only need to build a hash table for one of the sets.

Comment: @RaúlReguilloCarmona This is an algorithm, the syntax for the hash set is in a language i'm familiar in but most langauges have hash sets or hash tables you can use in a similar way.